# indexes in c # work with memory

Tags: c#

I began to parse the topic indexers in c # and ran into a problem while running a test task:

Index.cs:

```
class Index
{
    double[] arr;
    public int Length
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public double this[int x]
    {
        get { return arr[x]; }
        set
        {
            arr[x] = value;
        }
    }
    public Index(double[] arr1, int x, int y)
    {    
        Length = y;    

        arr = arr1;

        for (int i = x; i <= y; i++)
        {
            if (i == 0)
            {
                arr[i] = arr1[i + 1];
            }
            else
            {
                arr[i - 1] = arr1[i];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Program.cs

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    double[] array = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };        
    var indexer0 = new Index(array, 1, 2);
    Console.WriteLine(indexer0.Length);
    Console.WriteLine("Result = 2,3");       
    var indexer1 = new Index(array, 1, 2);
    Console.WriteLine(indexer1[0]);
    Console.WriteLine(indexer1[1]);
    Console.WriteLine("Copy 25");        
    var indexer2 = new Index(array, 1, 2);
    var indexer3 = new Index(array, 0, 2);
    indexer2[0] = 25;
    Console.WriteLine(indexer3[1]);
    Console.WriteLine("Array");
    foreach(var item in array)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

As you can see after calling indexer1, I want the array values ​​to change to 2 and 3, and I get 3.3 (I understand that this is due to the fact that when I call indexer0 I change the values ​​to 2.3, I then work with array 2,3,3,4, I can fix this by writing the values ​​to a temporary variable, but then I can not copy the value from indexer2 to indexer3 (the required value is 25.) Please help me deal with two of these problems.

Comment: Are you really need to reinvent a wheel? Replace your `Index` with [ArraySegemnt](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1hsbd92d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: @AleksAndreev, it's just practice

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with your implementation is that you are not making a copy of the original array. This creates a second reference to the same array

```
 arr = arr1;
```

so modifications inside the loop, like this one,

```
arr[i] = arr1[i + 1];
```

are moving around and overwriting elements of the original array.

Fix this by allocating a new array, and copying the content of the original one into it:

```
public int Length { get { return arr.Length; } }
public Index(double[] arr1, int x, int y) {
    arr = new double[y];
    Array.Copy(arr1, x, arr, 0, y);
}
```

Note that your `Index` will have a copy of the original array. If you want a "window" into the original array, not a copy (i.e. have changes to `Main`'s `array` be visible through `index1`, `index2`, etc. store `arr` unchanged, and also store the initial index in the private variable. You can now change the indexer implementation to do "index translation", i.e. subtracting the stored `x` from `index` to get the correct index:

```
class Index {
    private readonly double[] arr;
    private readonly int offset; // set this to x in the constructor
    public int Length { get { return arr.Length; } }
    public double this[int idx] {
        get { return arr[idx+offset]; }
        set { arr[idx+offset] = value; }
    }
    public Index(double[] arr1, int x, int y) {
        arr = arr1;
        offset = x;
    }
}
```

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/9wsX8X)

Comment: Thank you very much, because I thought that I could quickly solve this task, but in fact spent a lot of time and without your clue did not understand. Could you explain to me in more detail about the variable "offset", how do I need to initialize it?

Comment: @Tibomso Offset is for the situation when you do not copy. See edit.

Comment: @Tibomso Then you are looking for the "window" approach. Again, see the edit.

Comment: Forgive me, please, but I do not quite understand what you mean when you say "see edit"

Comment: I'll try to edit my code and change it in the question, could you see it later, if it's not difficult for you?

Comment: @Tibomso Refresh this page in the browser. You will see that I edited the answer at the bottom by adding a constructor for your `Index` class. This updated class implements a "window" into the original `array`, rather than making a copy.

Comment: How to be in this situation: `var indexer1 = new Index(array, 1, 2);  Console.WriteLine(indexer1[0]);` The index = 0, and X = 1, arises a exception - "System.IndexOutOfRangeException"

Comment: @Tibomso It should be `+ offset`, not `- offset`. I added a demo.

Comment: I am very grateful to you, now the subject with indexes became for me more clear, I will continue to practice!